# Force barcode output to write to a file

Tags: barcode-scanner, barcode

I have a [Symcode MJ-8200](https://smile.amazon.com/Barcode-Scanner-Omnidirectional-Hands-Free-Computer/dp/B06XD8MFFC?sa-no-redirect=1) barcode scanner that basically acts as a keyboard. I scan something, and then it will type the data of whatever it scanned into whatever text area my cursor is active in at that moment. The problem is that I have to be actively keeping a text editor open to write into it, and even so I can't ever save. I can keep scanning and writing, but it wont save unless I stop it and save. Is there any way I can force it to write straight into a file and save the information it writes?

Comment: There is a plugin called AutoSave for Notepad++ maybe you can use that?

Answer (score 2):

The very simplest solution:

For **windows**, hold Windows key, hit R, type `cmd` and ENTER to open a cmd prompt.
At the prompt, type:
`c:\> type >filename.txt` and press ENTER

Scan any number of barcodes, they will show in the display - and be saved into the file at the same time... as if you had typed them on the keyboard.
hold CTRL and hit Z, and hit ENTER - to end the "saving".

Typing `start filename.txt` (press ENTER) will act the same as if you had double-clicked the filname. *(`start .` to open the current folder in Explorer)*

---

For **Linux**, hold CTRL+SHIFT and hit T
At the prompt, type:
`$ cat >filename.txt` and press ENTER

(as above) Scan any barcodes, but hold CTRL and hit D to stop saving data.

`xdg-open filename.txt` is the equivalent to "start" for windows.

---

**Additional tip**
*Create a file named `start` and make it contain:*

```
#!/bin/bash
xdg-open "$*"  # replace with 'kde-open' for KDE
```

*Then do:

`$ chmod 755 start`
and place / move the file in / to a folder that is listed in you $PATH, and you'll have "start" working as for Windows.*